# Information about the fundamental particles

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, large-hadron-collider

Where can I get the most authentic information about the fundamental particles about all their properties(like charge, mass, spin, isospin, parity, hypercharge etc) which a particle physicist might be interested in?

Answer (score 4):

That's furnished by the Particle Data Group:
http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/tables/contents_tables.html

Comment: I was looking for the mean lifetime of B_d meson. Could not find it in PDG live.

Comment: @Seeker do you mean the B^0? 1,5 10^-12s . If not then could you state what quark content B_d is supposed to have?

Comment: Not a flavor physics person, but as far as I understand the experiments study mass eigenstates ($B^0$ and $\bar{B}^0$) rather than flavor eigenstates ($B_d$ and $\bar{B}_d$). So as lalala says, you should be looking at $B^0$ data and data about $B-\bar{B}$ mixing.

Comment: $B^0$ and $B^0_d$ are synonymous. $B^0_d$ and $B^+_u$ are sometimes used to distinguish from $B^0_s$ or $B^+_c$. The mass eigenstates are $B^0_H$ and $B^0_L$.

Comment: @Seeker It is here: http://pdglive.lbl.gov/DataBlock.action?node=S042T&init=0

Comment: Thank you very much friends. $B^o$ and $B^0_d$ are synonymous. That is what I missed. Thanks for this wonderful site PDG live. It is a treasure.